# What are reasons for TEB planner's feasibility check to fail?

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently experimenting with the TEB local planner and have the problem that the planner constantly fails with the following warning, even if there are no obstacles close to the path.

> TebLocalPlannerROS: trajectory is not feasible. Resetting planner...

The costmap-footprint of the robot is correct (at least in Rviz it looks good). The problem does not occur anymore when I decrease the parameter `feasibility_check_no_poses` to 3 or less. However, since there are no obstacles close to the path, I have the feeling, that something is wrong. Are there more parameters that influence the feasibility check that might cause this behaviour?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261834/what-are-reasons-for-teb-planner%27s-feasibility-check-to-fail?/) by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 382 on 2017-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After checking the code and adding some debug-output I found the issue: It is not a problem directly in the teb planner but the `footprintCost` function of the `base_local_planner::CostmapModel` sometimes fails to convert a footprint point to map coordinates, because it is outside of the local costmap (which silently results in the same cost as if there was an obstacle).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) with karma: 382 on 2017-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A Smit](https://answers.ros.org/users/34896/a-smit/) on 2018-04-30**:
I think I'm having the same problem, is there a solution?

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2018-05-02**:
@A Smit: The problem is the feasibility check looking too far ahead and thus going outside of the costmap (I opened [an issue](https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/teb_local_planner/issues/45) about this, which is still open, though). A quick workaround is to decrease the...

**Comment by [Felix Widmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/28762/felix-widmaier/) on 2018-05-02**:
... `feasibility_check_no_poses` parameter but the proper fix would be to improve the feasibility check so it does not try to check outside of the costmap.